# Saving a leaflet map as an html file

Tags: html, r, leaflet, maps

I've created a leaflet map of corn yield in Kansas using USDA NASS data. The problem I'm running into is exporting the leaflet into an html file using the command:

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(my_interactive_map, "kansas_corn2.html")
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in system.file(config, package = package) : 'package' must be of length 1
```

However, I can produce an html file by using Export > Save as Web Page.. from the Viewer pane.

[image: html leaflet export]

How can I achieve the same export result using the command line?
My code for making the map is:

```
my_interactive_map <- tm_shape(STATE) +
tm_polygons("Value", textNA = "Not Reported", 
          title = unit_desc, palette=c('#8290af','#512888','#190019'),
          auto.palette.mapping=FALSE, n = 6, style = "quantile", contrast = 0.9, colorNA = "#C0C0C0",
          border.col = "#E8E8E8", showNA = FALSE, legend.is.portrait = FALSE,
          legend.hist = FALSE, popup.vars = c("County: " = "COUNTY_NAME", "Value: " = "Value")) +
 tm_credits("U.S. Department of Agriculture, National Agriculture Statistics Service") +
 tm_format_World(title = paste(year_filt, prodn_practice_desc, commodity_desc, statisticcat_desc, "by", 
                            agg_level_desc, "for", state, sep = " "))
my_interactive_map
```

Comment: Have a look at [`library(mapview); mapshot()`](https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/reference/mapshot.html)

Comment: Thank you. But mapshot( ) gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using the tmap library. For that you could use the function detailed  [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/tmap/man/save_tmap.html):

```
library(tmap) 
save_tmap(my_interactive_map, "kansas_corn2.html")
```